# Facing problems with association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rails-models

I have three models User, Blog and Comment.

User.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible blah blah      
  has_many :blogs
  has_many :comments
end
```

Blog.rb

```
class Blog < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :user_id, :title, :content
    belongs_to :user
    has_many :comments
end
```

Comment.rb

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :user_id, :blog_id, :comment
    belongs_to :blog
    belongs_to :user
end
```

In create action of Comments Controller

```
def create
    @blog = Blog.where('id=?', params[:blog_id])
    @comment = @blog.comments.new(params[:comment])
    @comment.save
end
```

Here how will I pass id of current_user in the  :user_id field of comments table, I can make a hidden field for that but it's not safe. PLease help! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would this do what you want?

```
def create
  @blog = Blog.where('id=?', params[:blog_id])
  @comment = @blog.comments.new(params[:comment])
  @comment.user = current_user # force the user to be the logged-in user
  @comment.save
end
```

Comment: Here we are explicitly passing the user information, is there any other way of implementing this?

Comment: You're not passing any user information. You are getting the user out of the session. user_id is never appearing in forms or params. Just get it directly from session and put it directly into the comment object from the session like the above.

Comment: Yeah that's fine it will work but can you suggest some other way of doing this, like directly from the form? :)

Comment: Someone was saying about nested forms but I have no idea about how to use them

Comment: Sure you can put the user_id in the form and there are heaps of ways to do that - but the moment you put user information into the form - it means you have the user information visible to the person logged in.
Isn't that what you're trying to avoid?